# Unknown column in where clause in sub subquery used to get an average of a limit

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the error unknown column t1.s_ID in where clause. The other questions I've found relating to this don't have answers to this particular problem because I have to get an average of the last 5 records meeting the criteria.

What is the correct way to get an average of the most recent 5 records meeting the criteria?

```
SELECT
    t1.column1,
    t1.column2,
    round(
        (
            SELECT
                avg(t2.SPFL)
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        t3.SP/t3.SFL AS SPFL
                    FROM
                        table3 AS t3
                    WHERE
                        t3.s_ID = t1.s_ID 
                    AND t3.crit2 = t1.crit2
                    AND t3.crit3 = t1.crit3
                    ORDER BY
                        t3.Date DESC
                    LIMIT 5
                ) AS t2
        ) * t1.SFL
    ) AS est_SP
FROM
    table1 AS t1
```

Comment: Does `table1.s_ID` exist?

Comment: Yes. It's the third column in the table. This only throws a problem when I nest more than 1 subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is by using an explicit join and aggregation.  I think the following will work.  MySQL doesn't allow `limit` in subqueries for `IN`, but I'm pretty sure it works for `=`.  Note that this assumes that `date` has distinct values:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2,
       round(avg(t3.SP/t3.SFL) * t1.SFL) AS est_SP
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON t3.s_ID = t1.s_ID AND
        t3.crit2 = t1.crit2 AND
        t3.crit3 = t1.crit3
WHERE t3.date = (SELECT t3a.date
                 FROM table3 t3a
                 WHERE t3.s_ID = t3a.s_ID AND
                       t3.crit2 = t3a.crit2 AND
                       t3.crit3 = t3a.crit3
                 ORDER BY t3a.date DESC
                 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
                )
group by t1.column1, t1.column2;
```

If this doesn't work, there is another way to write the query using variables.  However, that might prevent the use of indexes for performance gains.

Comment: It's really clever the way you approach this. Using the average function tries to average the whole table though. To be sure I went through and tried it, and after several minutes it returned only one line.You'd think that getting the average of the last x number of values would be simple.

Comment: @AuntJamaima . . . Ooops, I left out the `group by`.  It would have generated an error in any database other than MySQL.

Comment: Ooops on my part because I should have thought about that already. I'm sorry I didn't look it over long enough. It works exactly as I had hoped. Thank you very much.